# Изменение списка в цикле

Tags: python

У меня есть код :

```
turn = []
while 1 > 0:
    turn.insert(0, 2)
    print(turn)
```

на выходе я хочу получить [2] , но он добавляет каждый раз на новое место 2 , так:
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ... 2] . Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
turn = []
turn.insert(0, 2)
print(turn)
```

Answer (score 2):

В первую очередь, `1 > 0` всегда `True`, так что красивее писать

```
while True:
```

Но результатом этого будет *бесконечный цикл*, и так его нужно где-нибудь прекратить командой `break`, что вы не делаете.

Теперь к тому, что вы хотели достичь. Вместо вашего сложного кода напишите просто

```
turn = [2]
print(turn)
```

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, потому что используете бесконечный цикл, в теле которого вставляете двойку в начале массива

Answer (score 0):

list.insert(i, x)   Вставляет на i-ый элемент значение x
Вы используете бесконечный цикл.
Проще, действительно, написать:

```
turn[0]=2
```

если Вам необходимо присвоить именно нулевому индексу это значение.